# from chainer.functions import caffeが使えない。

Tags: python, chainer

from chainer.functions import caffe
がインポート出来ません。
pip　install chainer
のコマンドを打っただけです。
他のchainer.functionsはインポート出来ています。

動作環境
Windows10
VSCode
Python3.9

Answer (score 0):

`from chainer.functions import caffe`を
`from chainer.links import caffe`に書き換えるとエラーを解消できます。

参考資料: [caffeを使った画像認識プログラムの実行について](https://teratail.com/questions/82964)

`chainer 7.8.0`で発生するエラー詳細:

```
>>> from chainer.functions import caffe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'caffe' from 'chainer.functions' (C:\Users\payaneco\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\chainer\functions\__init__.py)
```